# Chrome extension stylesheet (.css) is not being loaded after navigation

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension is supposed to work with `https://web.whatsapp.com/`:

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://web.whatsapp.com/"],
      "js": ["entry/content-script/cs.js"],
      "css": ["entry/content-script/zen-mode-ui.css"]
    }
  ],
```

When I load `web.whatsapp.com` directly, in a new tab - all is fine: the stylesheet is injected like it's supposed to:
[image: injected]

But! If I first go to `whatsapp.com` and there click the link to Whatsapp Web - when `web.whatsapp.com` loads, the css is NOT injected:
[image: not injected]
There is no *injected stylesheet* snippet.
Although, the content script loads just fine.
If I then refresh the page - all is good.
Is it a bug in chrome extensions engine itself?

Comment: Add `*` and match all subdomains: `"matches": ["https://*.whatsapp.com/*"]`, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66633274).

Comment: @wOxxOm, no this is not an SPA or a subdomain issue. I tried `"matches": ["https://*.whatsapp.com/"]` before posting the Q and it didn't work. But! changing it to `"matches": ["https://web.whatsapp.com/*"]` did work! Do you have any idea as to why??

Comment: Sounds like a bug alright.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `"matches": ["https://web.whatsapp.com/*"]` (note the final asterisk) have fixed it.
Looks like a bug in Chrome. [Track here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1188210).